# Refresh fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have the following code:

```
builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.Add_Note, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

    editNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    linearLayoutTimeCalories.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  }
});

dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

What i need is to refresh the view after changing the visibility. I tried already with view.invalidate();
        view.postInvalidate();
        view.refreshDrawableState(); but no result.

Comment: What do you mean by 'refresh'? What View do you want to refresh?

Comment: It's a fragment. I'm trying to make the views visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom Dialog instead of using a builder. (i.e. MyDialog extends Dialog).

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog{

    public MyDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void refresh(){

    }
}
```

Then hold the dialog instance in your activity/fragment, when you need to refresh the dialog you can call the "refresh()" method in your custom dialog instance.